# Periodic progression which mean is a convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a periodic progression $S=\{a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,\ldots,a,b,c,d\}$ and I compute its mean as function of the elements cover i.e.

$\displaystyle A_j=\frac{1}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{j}S_i$, then $A_1=a,A_2=\frac{a+b}{2},\ldots$. I know in the $\displaystyle\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}$ $A_j=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$ which is the average of $S$ in one period. How do I put down the rigorous proof of this results ?

Note. I got the result by computing the series by programing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $m$ items
repeated periodically,
$(a_k)_{i=1}^k
$.
Let
$A
=\frac1{m}\sum_{h=1}^m a_h
$.

Then
to get the average of
the first $n$
items,
write
$n = im+j$
where
$0 \le j \lt m$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{n}\sum_{h=1}^n a_h
&=\frac1{im+j}\sum_{h=1}^{im+j} a_h\\
&=\frac1{im+j}\left(\sum_{h=1}^{im} a_h+\sum_{h=im+1}^{im+j} a_h\right)
\qquad\text{split off beyond the multiples of } m\\
&=\frac1{im+j}\left(i\sum_{h=1}^{m} a_h+\sum_{h=im+1}^{im+j} a_h\right)\\
&=\frac1{im+j}\left(imA+\sum_{h=im+1}^{im+j} a_h\right)
\qquad\text{since there are }i\text{ copies of the } m \text{ values}\\
&=\frac1{im+j}imA+\frac1{im+j}\sum_{h=im+1}^{im+j} a_h\\
&=\frac{im}{im+j}A+\frac1{im+j}\sum_{h=1}^{j} a_h
\qquad\text{since the }a_h \text{ repeat}\\
&=\frac{im+j-j}{im+j}A+\frac1{im+j}\sum_{h=1}^{j} a_h
\qquad\text{standard technique to get } A \text{ by itself}\\
&=(1-\frac{j}{im+j})A+\frac1{im+j}\sum_{h=1}^{j} a_h\\
&=A-\frac{j}{im+j}A+\frac1{im+j}\sum_{h=1}^{j} a_h\\
&=A-\frac1{im+j}(jA+\sum_{h=1}^{j} a_h)\\
&=A-\frac1{n}(jA-\sum_{h=1}^{j} a_h)
\qquad\text{had "+" inside}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
|\frac1{n}\sum_{h=1}^n a_h-A|
&=|\frac1{n}(jA-\sum_{h=1}^{j} a_h)|\\
&\le\frac1{n}(m|A|+\sum_{h=1}^{m} |a_h|)\\
\end{array}
$

Since all terms inside
of the final absolute values
are bounded,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac1{n}\sum_{h=1}^n a_h-A|
= 0$
or
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n}\sum_{h=1}^n a_h
= A$.

Comment: I attempted something similar, but forgot how to do the "A" by itself technique. Thanks this was really helpful and made me relearn all series  stuff I forgot  over time.